# Can C variable declared to be nothing?

Tags: c++, jvm, var

There exists a C++ code shown below:

```
byte                _jfr_towrite      : 1,       // Flags
                    _caller_sensitive : 1,
                    _force_inline     : 1,
                    _hidden           : 1,
                    _dont_inline      : 1,
                                      : 3;
```

see the last line,it is strange that there is nothing before ':' and after ','.the variable name is just nothing.
The code is from jdk8/openjdk/hotspot/src/share/vm/oops/method.hpp line 113.
I am deeply studying jdk and I need help,please.

Comment: And your question is....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<name> : <size>` designates *bit fields*. Each of the five named variables in your code occupies a single bit. The remaining three bits are explicitly designated as unused by the syntax with missing name,

This is not something that can be done to any C++ variable, but only to bit fields. You can use the syntax that you show to provide *padding* in bit fields within a `struct` or `class`, without creating an unused named field. It does not need to be the last field in the `struct` or `class`: you can create padding in the middle of a bit field sequence, too. The actual placement of the bit fields, including any padding, is implementation-defined, so it does not matter where you place it in relation to other bit fields.

Comment: Note that the order and spacing of bitfields are implementation-defined anyway, so the padding could be anywhere in relation to the other fields.